# Accessing MFC classes inside ATL project in VC++ 2008

Tags: com, mfc, visual-c++

I have created an ATL Project with all default options using VC++ 2008.

I have added Simple ATL object (interface IDemo) and some interface moethos inside the simple object.

I want to use MFC classes (e.g. CDatabase, CRecordset and lots more) inside my ATL project.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

MFC has to be initialized. Create a dummy Console project and include MFC support to see what bits need to be added.